Pymongo: automatic IP
I am writing an application using Pymongo to access a database on MongoDb Atlas using some basic syntax such as:
import pymongo as pm

url = "mongodb+srv://user:password@clusterName.ecc.."

client = pm.MongoClient(url)

db  = client.get_database('name_db')

My problem is that every time I connect from a different IP I need to login manually to the mongoDB Atlas panel and add the new IP. Is there a pymongo function able to add the user IP automatically ?
Sorry if the question is trivial, I am still new to the mongoDB world.
Thank you!

What if somebody else attempts to connect from an IP that has not already been authorized?

Good question. But the database is created by the user, so user name and password should be included in the URL string. But if the IP changes, e.g. the user connects from a different location or computer, MongoDB Atlas  doesn't recognize the new IP automatically.

My question was largely rhetorical.  The point is that this is a security feature.  Perhaps one that you don't want, but a security feature all the same.  It is naive to suppose that an adversary could never obtain a valid username / password pair.  Requiring authorization of the IP provides an additional layer of security (albeit still not insurmountable).  I am well aware that this does not answer the question -- that's why it's a comment, not an answer -- but one thing to take from it is that it is plausible that there is no function such as you want.

Thank you for your clarification. But now I wonder how all the other database platforms, e.g. Facebook, Google ecc..., allow a user to connect from different IP address securely.

Many of them use SSL to reduce the likelihood of credentials being stolen. Some of them can or do use SSL or similar cryptographic means to identify and authenticate users, instead of usernames and passwords.  Some may proxy inbound connections in a way that sidesteps the issue.  Some may use databases that don't require machine authorization, even though that's less secure.  There are many, many other possibilities.

If your user may have any IP-Address, then you must permit any IP-Address to connect, there is not much you can change. If you like to white-list certain IP's automatically, then it is the same as white-listing them by default.
Is it really any IP? You can also white-list IP ranges, e.g. 180.120.32.0/24 for all IP's from 180.120.32.0 to 180.120.32.255
Regarding you actual question: Yes, that's possible.
Either with Atlas CLI (or see atlasapi):
 atlas accessLists create --currentIp

or with Atlas API:
curl --user "{PUBLIC-KEY}:{PRIVATE-KEY}" \
   --digest \
   --header "Accept: application/vnd.atlas.2024-05-30+json" \
   -X POST "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v2/groups/{groupId}/accessList" \
   --data '[ { "ipAddress": "180.120.32.120" } ]'

To manage IP Access List entries, you must have Project Owner access to the project, which means you grant full admin privileges to your user. The user may do everything. For example drop the entire project or upgrade the cluster and you will have to pay 1000$ per day for your Atlas MongoDB. You should not grant this to your end-user!

White-list all IP which your uses may have. There is no other possibility. You cannot block and allow the access at the same time.

Thank you for your explanation! I understand the security issue. So I wonder how can a user have access to his database without the possibility of damaging the whole project?
I will try to give more context. I am trying to develop an App in Django where  a user can login with a browser and access his database. During testing I simply noticed that as soon as I change location I lose the connection to the database because I manually have to re-validate the IP.

Every user has a username+password (or a x.509 certificate). What else are you looking for?

That is correct, every user has a username+password. So perhaps, username+password and white-list IP should allow the DB connection securely?

Yes it does, and that's what thousands millions of web services do.
